# C言語でxを右シフト、左シフトする関数をアセンブリ言語で表現したい

Tags: assembly, x86

以下のC言語のコードをアセンブリ言語に変換したいのですが、なぜ算術右シフトをする際に `%cl` となるのかどなたか教えていただけないでしょうか

C言語版

```
void shift(int x, int y){
    x <<= 2;
    x >>= y;
    return x;
}
```

アセンブリ言語版(xは%ebp+8、yは$ebp+12に格納されているとする)

```
movl 8(%ebp), %eax
shll $2, %eax
movl 12(%ebp), %ecx
sarl %cl, %eax /*ここで%ecx, %eaxでは駄目なのか？*/
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual、Volume 2B: Instruction Set Reference, M-U 582ページ](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/7c/f1/253667-sdm-vol-2b.pdf#page=582)にて

> The count operand can be an immediate value or the CL register.

と説明されているように、コンパイル時に決定される即値か、実行時に動的に決定するのであれば`CL`レジスターを使用する仕様です。

具体的には32bit SAL命令は

```
SAL r/m32, 1     ; 1bitシフト
SAL r/m32, imm8  ; 固定シフト
SAL r/m32, CL    ; 動的シフト
```

の３形式です。

---

`SAL`に限らずx86命令では使用できるレジスターが指定されている命令が所々にあります。
汎用レジスターは対等と思われるかもしれませんが、[各レジスターにはそれぞれの役割](https://ja.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86%E3%82%A2%E3%82%BB%E3%83%B3%E3%83%96%E3%83%A9/x86%E3%82%A2%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AD%E3%83%86%E3%82%AF%E3%83%81%E3%83%A3#.E6.B1.8E.E7.94.A8.E3.83.AC.E3.82.B8.E3.82.B9.E3.82.BF_.28GPR.29)があり、`CL`レジスターはカウンターだったりします。シフトカウントだけでなくループカウントなど別の命令でもカウンターとして使われています。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます! 調べてみるととりわけシフト回数は0-31回までなのでCLレジスタの下位5ビットの値を見るんですね